# Java Syntax Explanation for attached snippet, ArrayList Enumeration

Tags: java, syntax

I am following through the KiloBolt Tutorial on Game Dev and the following code appears

```
ArrayList projectiles = robot.getProjectiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++) {
                Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
                if (p.isVisible() == true) {
                    p.update();
                } else {
                    projectiles.remove(i);
                }
```

I am really struggling on how this line hangs together

```
Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
```

1. `Projectile p` he is creating a new `Projectile` called `p` from the projectile class here?
2. `(Projectile) projectiles.get(i);` what is this? I'm not sure why it is `(Projectile)` then getting the projectile arraylist element? What is the bracketed section indicating?

Comment: Google "java casting" or something of that sort. On the other hand, that seems like it might be an old tutorial if it doesn't use generics... Might want to look around for a different one.

Comment: I should point out that this is pretty horrible code, not just for 2014, but for whatever bygone era in which this was written. There are three or four crimes against nature here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, looking it up now :)

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Apart from that, the code seems to contain at least one bug as it will skip the next element after removing an item.

Comment: I'm not liking the look of that if statement..

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good place to learn the very basics of a programming language.

Comment: You should first learn Java before trying to learn to work on something using Java. Besides, this problem won't arise if you use generics and have defined the attribute as `List<Projectile>` instead of a plain raw `ArrayList`.

Comment: I am trying to learn java along side ,  this but most resources I have came across just cover the basic math operators loops, over and over, rather than going into any real depth :/ , i.e java in 24 hrs and along that lines, I thought a project that I was interested in would spur my understanding :/

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, Ill try pushing more on learning java inside out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific questions:

1. He's creating a reference to a specific, already existing projectile returned from robot.getProjectiels()
2. He's getting a specific Projectile by index from the array backed list (ArrayList). Since he's not using generics, he has to then cast it to a Projectile object.

However...this code looks quite out of date.

Hard to tell what the end goal is here. If you're looking to call update on all "visible" projectiles and end up with a List that only has visible projectiles, I would structure the code as such:

```
List<Projectile> visibleProjectiles = new ArrayList<Projectile>();
for (Projectile p : robot.getProjectiles()) {
    if (p.isVisible()) {
        p.update();
        visibleProjectiles.add(p);
    }
}
```

Note:

- the use of generics
- the use of the java-style foreach
- that `p.isVisible() == true` is unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 2):

The get method (`projectiles.get(i)`) returns a Java object of type Object. Because of this, the code here is casting the object returned by `projectiles.get(i)` to be a Projectile. As has been mentioned in many comments (as well as an answer by Elliott_Frisch), this step could by replacing the very first line with `List<Projectile> projectiles = robot.getProjectiles();`

In essence, this snippet of code iterates through every Projectile in projectiles, and checks to see if it is visible. If it is, its position (presumably) is updated. If not, it is removed from the projectiles Enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

An ArrayList is backed by an array - so

```
Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
```

Gets a reference to the `Projectile` at position `i` from the array backing the `projectiles` List. If there is no element at `i` and `i` is within the size of the container then you would get `null` (e.g. it's not a new `Projectile` with get).

The cast is necessary because this `ArrayList` is a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Hence it is necessary to cast `Object` to `Projectile`. If possible, use a generic type with the container,

```
List<Projectile> projectiles = robot.getProjectiles();
```

Then

```
Projectile p = projectiles.get(i); // <-- no cast with generic type.
```

Comment: I feel like the answer should really contain information about casting.

Answer (score 1):

The term used for what is happening here is Type Casting. If you Google it, you can find some good article explaining the same. To give you an idea what's happening here, you have a List (ArrayList) named projectiles. It can contain any type of object like "Projectile" or "Artillery" unless you restrict it using Generics. In your case this list contains "Projectile" objects. You can refer them by the type of objects they are and since all objects are inherited from Object class you can always  do some thing like

```
     Object p = projectiles.get(i);
```

without using the bracket (Projectile) stuff.

But since we want the original "Projectile" object we saved, will need to type cast them like.

```
     Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
```

Why you need to do that? Because once you inserted the object in List that accepts any type objects, the information about exact type of object added is gone. The compiler cannot figure the type object coming out List. It can be any thing and here you will to help it out by explicit specifying the type (casting). If the type is wrong, you will get a run time ClassCastException.

Comment: Well Explained,, Thank you